# Losing transparency of png with php magickwand and imagemagick when rotation is applied

Tags: php, imagemagick, magickwand

Hi I'm porting a script from a windows environment running MagickWand 0.1.8 and ImageMagick 6.2.9 where transparency worked fine with MagickRotateImage.

New environment is linux running MagickWand 1.0.8 with ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 and transparency gets lost and it shows black as the background as soon as my logo image gets rotated.

From what I've found online, seems that PixelSetColor($bg,"none") doesn't work with the newer versions hence the black.  Ultimately, I need to know what to replace PixelSetColor($bg,"none") with.  I just don't have a background in image creation so struggling a bit with this.

First my php runs this function which makes a local 60x60 version of 600x600 png image gotten from a url.

```
function makeThumb($fileContents){
    GLOBAL $localImgPath1;
    GLOBAL $localImgPath2;
    $wand = NewMagickWand();
    $lg = MagickReadImageBlob($wand,$fileContents);
    $lg_w = MagickGetImageWidth($wand);
    $lg_h = MagickGetImageHeight($wand);
    $max = max($lg_h,$lg_w);
    $scale_factor = 60/$max;
    MagickResizeImage($wand,$lg_w*$scale_factor,$lg_h*$scale_factor, MW_GaussianFilter, .7);
    MagickWriteImage($wand, $localImgPath1);
    if($localImgPath2!="")
        MagickWriteImage($wand, $localImgPath2);
    $resized_w = MagickGetImageWidth($wand);
    $resized_h = MagickGetImageHeight($wand);
    DestroyMagickWand($wand);
}
```

then, I use this to read that locally written png image and rotate it:

```
$logo = NewMagickWand();
$bg = NewPixelWand();
PixelSetColor($bg,"none");
MagickReadImage($logo, $localImgPath1);
MagickRotateImage($logo, $bg, $r);
header('Content-Type: image/PNG');
MagickEchoImageBlob($logo);
DestroyPixelWand($bg);
DestroyMagickWand($logo);
```

I've tried things like adding:

```
$transparent = NewPixelWand("#FFFFFF");
PixelSetAlpha($transparent, 0);
//and then making the rotate call:
MagickRotateImage($logo, $transparent, $r);
```

Also tried adding MagickSetImageAlphaChannel($logo, MW_SetAlphaChannel); before the rotate step. Saw some posts mentioning that method but possibly that's not the correct way to use it.  Not sure.

I also have the same problem in a script that draws a text string with a set font onto the image.  Black immediately shows there even before rotation is applied so hoping same fix for the logo script will be useable by the font script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a choice of four values for a transparent background.  Try each in turn:

```
"none", "transparent", "#00000000", or "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried all 4 of those in turn as the value for PixelSetColor ( ex: PixelSetColor($bg,"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"); ) but still get black showing through when rotated.

Comment: Try adding a call to `MagickSetBackgroundColor` and/or `MagickSetImageBackgroundColor` after your call to `PixelSetColor` ( e.g. `MagickSetImageBackgroundColor($logo, $bg);`

Comment: Thanks for the continued help, so far no good though.  Tried using each of those separately: $logo = NewMagickWand();
$bg = NewPixelWand();
PixelSetColor($bg,"none"); //cycled through all 4 of your suggested values
MagickSetImageBackgroundColor($logo, $bg);
MagickReadImage($logo, $localImgPath1);
MagickRotateImage($logo, $bg, $r);
header('Content-Type: image/PNG');
MagickEchoImageBlob($logo);
...also tried moving those to after the read image and even after the rotate image but no good. Could it be a step I'm missing on the other code where I write the png to disk initially?

Comment: At this point, think it may just be a bug with ImageMagick 6.5.4-7.  Found this post that leads me to that conclusion: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20312.  Going to try and get a later version of IM to see if it resolves the issue.  Will provide an update after that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with ImageMagick 6.5.4-7.  Must have been a buggy release.  Upgraded to 6.8.4-10 and above code works fine, PixelSetColor($bg,"none") works for the transparency.